# Delegate method for end the document from UIDocumentInterationController

Tags: ipad

I am using UIDocumentInterationController for showing the document in my iPad Application.
I want to perform something when document is closed.I used the following delegate method :-

```
- (void)documentInteractionControllerDidEndPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller{
    NSLog(@"End Document");
}
```

But It does not work.Please let me know which delegate method is called when we press the done button for hide the documentController ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have not found any solution for this problem

Answer (score 3):

When using Xcode 4 with ARC, you cannot call retain. In order to get it working with ARC, just declare your docController as an ivar in header file, and then create your docController normally in your code.

`docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];`

Answer (score 2):

I got this working by adding a retain call after the presentPreviewAnimated call.
Then in the DidEndPreview method I set it to autorelease.
Let me know if this helps or you need any more information such as a code example.